# Cordova - Multiple dex files define (annotation)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a project with ionic. After I installed the [Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) I'm not able to build the project for android anymore!

The command

```
ionic build android
```

gives me this error message

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

I'm reading a lot of tutorials/answers about this error and it seems to be related to the use of the Facebook Plugin with the [Push Notification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

It's two days I'm trying a lot of different solutions, but none of those is working :(

Here are some information about my configuration:

```
plugin com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin version 2.5.0
plugin com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect version 0.11.0 (installed with the local repository, as indicated on github)
cordova version 5.0
ionic version 1.6.3
```

It looks like this problem is related to the "support-annotations" library loaded several times. Buy I really don't know how this is possible and where I can check it.

Can you help me? Do you have any idea of how to make this working?
Is there a ionic/cordova configuration file where I can check the dependencies?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple dex files error is raised because of using multiple support jar files in the ionic / cordova project

you need to change build.gradle under platforms/android

find the below line

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'
```

after add these below lines

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! My project combines cordova-plugin-background-push and cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing giving the Multiple dex files define error. Thanks @jagadeesh

Answer (score 2):

i solved same problem in my app the problem is

```
 com.android.support:support-v4:+
```

com.android.support:support-v4:+ file exist in /platforms/android/phonegap-facebook-plugin/Myapp-FacebookLib/libs

if you want only used facebook and Push Notification Plugin then simply **commit the line in project.properties**

```
#cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:+
```

**Best way to solved this problem**

```
1 First delete the android-support-v4.jar from /platforms/android/phonegap-facebook-plugin/Myapp-FacebookLib/libs

2 second step create a file name build-extras.gradle in /platforms/android/phonegap-facebook-plugin/Myapp-FacebookLib/
```

**and type in file**

```
dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+" }
```

Comment: @Anurag pandey I am also stuggling in this but not with facebook but with calendar here is my question plese help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538143/ionic-build-android-command-fails-with-an-exception-after-trying-to-add-ngcordov/37539362#37539362

Answer (score 0):

Push- and Facebook Plugins are conflicting by using different versions of android support libraries.

See my answer to this question: [Android Studio cordova Push plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421586/android-studio-cordova-push-plugin/32794948#32794948)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Google Analytics plugin with One Signal plugin and finally it was resolved by installing the plugins in different order;

1. first install Google Analytics
2. and then One Signal plugin, if you install in reverse order you will get that error.

This was our config:

- Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 3.3.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to project.properties will resolve all of the V4 error instances.

```
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
```