# Android Studio cordova Push plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova

Can someone help me? I'm new to Android studio.

After I installed the plugin push in my project, I received the following error message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I use Android studio 1.3.2  with Cordova https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.

I've been searching for days, but can not find a solution

I hope you mean this file

```
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
*/

import java.util.regex.Pattern
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

String doEnsureValueExists(filePath, props, key) {
    if (props.get(key) == null) {
        throw new GradleException(filePath + ': Missing key required "' + key + '"')
    }
    return props.get(key)
}

String doGetProjectTarget() {
    def props = new Properties()
    file('project.properties').withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }
    return doEnsureValueExists('project.properties', props, 'target')
}

String[] getAvailableBuildTools() {
    def buildToolsDir = new File(getAndroidSdkDir(), "build-tools")
    buildToolsDir.list()
        .findAll { it ==~ /[0-9.]+/ }
        .sort { a, b -> compareVersions(b, a) }
}

String doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools(String minBuildToolsVersion) {
    def availableBuildToolsVersions
    try {
        availableBuildToolsVersions = getAvailableBuildTools()
    } catch (e) {
        println "An exception occurred while trying to find the Android build tools."
        throw e
    }
    if (availableBuildToolsVersions.length > 0) {
        def highestBuildToolsVersion = availableBuildToolsVersions[0]
        if (compareVersions(highestBuildToolsVersion, minBuildToolsVersion) < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "No usable Android build tools found. Highest installed version is " +
                highestBuildToolsVersion + "; minimum version required is " +
                minBuildToolsVersion + ".")
        }
        highestBuildToolsVersion
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version " +
            minBuildToolsVersion + " or higher.")
    }
}

// Return the first non-zero result of subtracting version list elements
// pairwise. If they are all identical, return the difference in length of
// the two lists.
int compareVersionList(Collection aParts, Collection bParts) {
    def pairs = ([aParts, bParts]).transpose()
    pairs.findResult(aParts.size()-bParts.size()) {it[0] - it[1] != 0 ? it[0] - it[1] : null}
}

// Compare two version strings, such as "19.0.0" and "18.1.1.0". If all matched
// elements are identical, the longer version is the largest by this method.
// Examples:
//   "19.0.0" > "19"
//   "19.0.1" > "19.0.0"
//   "19.1.0" > "19.0.1"
//   "19" > "18.999.999"
int compareVersions(String a, String b) {
    def aParts = a.tokenize('.').collect {it.toInteger()}
    def bParts = b.tokenize('.').collect {it.toInteger()}
    compareVersionList(aParts, bParts)
}

String getAndroidSdkDir() {
    def rootDir = project.rootDir
    def androidSdkDir = null
    String envVar = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
    def localProperties = new File(rootDir, 'local.properties')
    String systemProperty = System.getProperty("android.home")
    if (envVar != null) {
        androidSdkDir = envVar
    } else if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDirProp = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDirProp != null) {
            androidSdkDir = sdkDirProp
        } else {
            sdkDirProp = properties.getProperty('android.dir')
            if (sdkDirProp != null) {
                androidSdkDir = (new File(rootDir, sdkDirProp)).getAbsolutePath()
            }
        }
    }
    if (androidSdkDir == null && systemProperty != null) {
        androidSdkDir = systemProperty
    }
    if (androidSdkDir == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Unable to determine Android SDK directory.")
    }
    androidSdkDir
}

def doExtractIntFromManifest(name) {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile(name + "=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
}

def doPromptForPassword(msg) {
    if (System.console() == null) {
        def ret = null
        new SwingBuilder().edt {
            dialog(modal: true, title: 'Enter password', alwaysOnTop: true, resizable: false, locationRelativeTo: null, pack: true, show: true) {
                vbox {
                    label(text: msg)
                    def input = passwordField()
                    button(defaultButton: true, text: 'OK', actionPerformed: {
                        ret = input.password;
                        dispose();
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        if (!ret) {
            throw new GradleException('User canceled build')
        }
        return new String(ret)
    } else {
        return System.console().readPassword('\n' + msg);
    }
}

def doGetConfigXml() {
    def xml = file("res/xml/config.xml").getText()
    // Disable namespace awareness since Cordova doesn't use them properly
    return new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
}

def doGetConfigPreference(name, defaultValue) {
    name = name.toLowerCase()
    def root = doGetConfigXml()

    def ret = defaultValue
    root.preference.each { it ->
        def attrName = it.attribute("name")
        if (attrName && attrName.toLowerCase() == name) {
            ret = it.attribute("value")
        }
    }
    return ret
}

// Properties exported here are visible to all plugins.
ext {
    // These helpers are shared, but are not guaranteed to be stable / unchanged.
    privateHelpers = {}
    privateHelpers.getProjectTarget = { doGetProjectTarget() }
    privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools = { doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools('19.1.0') }
    privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest = { name -> doExtractIntFromManifest(name) }
    privateHelpers.promptForPassword = { msg -> doPromptForPassword(msg) }
    privateHelpers.ensureValueExists = { filePath, props, key -> doEnsureValueExists(filePath, props, key) }

    // These helpers can be used by plugins / projects and will not change.
    cdvHelpers = {}
    // Returns a XmlParser for the config.xml. Added in 4.1.0.
    cdvHelpers.getConfigXml = { doGetConfigXml() }
    // Returns the value for the desired <preference>. Added in 4.1.0.
    cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference = { name, defaultValue -> doGetConfigPreference(name, defaultValue) }
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: I'm new to gradle so I hope you mean this file.

Comment: If I put this line in comment, it seems to work. //compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"

Comment: surely some will conflict with the support v7 and then does not make you fill the Gradle..

Comment: I do not know the implications of removing this string

Comment: pur real gradle file..I do not know which files you put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin is deprecated, try using the new one that replaces that one.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Answer (score 0):

The error is the result of conflicting plugin jar libraries.

Look for libs like com.android.support.v4.jar and similar...

To get around this you need to search for (forked) plugins that already resolved the conflict.

Sadly enough simply deinstalling the "Problem-Plugin" often does not remove the error because there are dependencies *left overs* somewhere in the files used by `cordove build`

In that case search manually for these *left overs* (for example in `../your_project/package.json`) and remove all occurences of the deinstalled plugin.