# Enable Multidex for Android in Ionic framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-multidex

Is there a way to set enable multidex (https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex) for Android if I build apps using Ionic Framework ?

Comment: View, I things same problem [Cordova - Multiple dex files define (annotation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727318/cordova-multiple-dex-files-define-annotation/33777507#33777507)

Answer (score 7):

For those still having this issue, I've fixed it by installing cordova-plugin-multidex

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-enable-multidex
```

Check it out: [Multidex for Cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-enable-multidex)

Answer (score 6):

There is [a plugin](https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex) that enables multidex. To install it, run:

`cordova plugin add --save https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex`

And try building again. The build may take a little longer than usual, but your app should compile without troubles.

Comment: I think the correct command would is: 

`cordova plugin add --save https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex`

Comment: @LucasD'Avila : You're right. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: my app on cordova 9 starts to crash after using this

Comment: @MoblizeIT the package mentioned in my answer hasn't been updated in 2+ years. I suggest you try another package, or do a clean build.

Answer (score 3):

For people using `androidx` and `cordova-android: 8` is interested in this solution, I created a fork that supports the file structure and class names of these new versions. Also works with Ionic.

```sh
cordova plugin add --save https://github.com/c00/cordova-multidex
```

Note that this is only relevant if you are still supporting a `minSdk` less than 21. At 21, multidexing is no longer needed as there is some built-in fix for it. So in that case, just remove the multidex plugin (if you had it) and things should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
cordova plugin add --save https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex
```

Answer (score 1):

```
To fix this —

Install couple of androidx plugins to solve the issue. So simply run the following commands in your project root:

Add plugin to enable AndroidX in the project

1. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx

2. Add plugin to patch existing plugin source that uses the Android Support Library to use AndroidX

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

3. Now run the following commands in your project root:

cordova clean
ionic cordova build android
```

https://medium.com/@AnkitMaheshwariIn/ionic-android-error-while-merging-dex-archives-unable-to-merge-dex-in-ionic-3f6272899aab