# Ionic build - The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-multidex

No matter what I do build always fail with multidex error. I have tried below things:-
 - uninstalling build tools 24
 - new basic project
 - removing re-adding platform
 - changing target sdk for build using

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

Please help. I am stuck.

[image: Logs with exception]

Comment: You need to have multidexing enabled for Android if the project is too large. See the post here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259679/enable-multidex-for-android-in-ionic-framework